# All tasks in a process are not found in act_ru_execution table

Tags: activiti

I have  an activiti process. When I want to get all active tasks. When I query I get first task always even though third task is going on. I am unable to figure out why act_ru_execution doesnot have actual entry of the task instead of having a fake entry as first task all the time. I am really stuck at it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Using this code I tried to get active tasks:
runtimeService.getActiveActivityIds(processInstanceId)

Comment: Can you add your code? How will you get the tasks?

Comment: Using this code runtimeService.getActiveActivityIds(processInstanceId)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method to get the all active task.

```
List<Task> list = processEngine.getTaskService().createTaskQuery().active().list();
```

Comment: It seems activiti does not store tasks in db unless it's user task or receive task or async task. Came to know now. But problem is if task is async then it can be executed by any node in clustered env and will not have access to resources created locally by previous tasks. So, seems like I cannot get that info from db for service tasks(non-async)

Comment: Yes, service task doesn't save in db. But async service task save as a job in db.